# How to put a Chromebook into Developer Mode

Tags: chromebook

[This article](https://www.androidpolice.com/how-to-enter-chromeos-developer-mode/) says how to enable Chromebook into Developer Mode,

1. Turn off your Chromebook.
2. Turn your Chromebook back on.
3. While your Chromebook is restarting, simultaneously hold the `Esc key`, `Refresh key`, and `Power button`.

At this point, I receive an error `please insert a recovery USB stick or an SD card`.

If I turn it off and back, it boots fine.

I've tried the 3 steps above multiple times and every time the message above appears.

I only need to edit the hosts file.

Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 3 11.6-inch Chromebook
Google Chrome OS
Version 110.0.5481.112 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Comment: According to [XDA Devs](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-turn-on-chrome-os-developer-mode/), looks like you're expected to press Ctrl+D when that message appears.

Comment: Yes, you're right, add an answer if you like